# Regex find a word but exclude a bigger word

Tags: regex

I want to search for a word but exclude matches which contain a bigger word, e.g. I want to search for "dog" but exclude matches containing "doggie".

So "big dog" and "big doggy" should match but not "big doggie"

The following should NOT match

```
big doggie
bigdoggie
doggiebig
bigdoggiebad
```

The following SHOULD match

```
bigdog
dogbig
baddogbig
```

The best I can come up with is this, but it doesn't work:

```
(?!doggie)dog
```

Comment: Use the `\b` word boundary escape sequence.

Comment: What is the tool/language?

Comment: @Barmar so if I want more than one word, (?!doggy|doggie)dog\b to both exclude doggy and doggie?

Comment: The problem with \b is it only does complete words I want dogs to match

Comment: Please update the question to include that detail. Are there any other words you also want to match?

Comment: @Barmar I have put some cases in

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a negative look ahead:

```
dog(?!gie)
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/5RRbhNg9FL) working with all your examples, eg

```
big dog (matches)
big doggy (matches)
big doggie (no match)
```

---

Incidentally, your attempt works too (it only suffers from a slight duplication of "dog" in the expression).

Answer (score 0):

Use the word-boundary character (`\b`):

```
\bdog\b
```

Comment: @stribizhev Well, yeah. But since OP is able to use negative look-aheads, I assumed that `\b` would be available

Comment: how does this match `"doggie"` as per question?

Comment: I want more than just complete words, I want dogs to match

Comment: @Bohemian The question says it should **not** match `doggie`.

Comment: @Barmar oops - I meant `"doggy"` - it should match `"doggy"`